# How to get selected item (row) value in Vaadin grid?

Tags: java, vaadin

I have a grid with one column named "Object". I have one row/item under the column with the value of "Location". When I try to get the string value of the row, I get an int value of 1. I need the string value of the row which is "Location", not the number of the row:

```
queryLabel1.setValue(grid.getSelectedRow().toString());
```

How can I get the string value of this row when it is selected and put the value in a Label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer in Vaadin forums: https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/14343801

This made it work for me:

```
Object selected = ((SingleSelectionModel) grid.getSelectionModel()).getSelectedRow();
grid.getContainerDataSource().getItem(selected).getItemProperty("Object")).getValue();
```